# Jmeter - how to output extra info (jmeter variable(s)) on Response Assertion failure

Tags: jmeter

So I added a Response Assertion on the main sample and apply to that and all sub-samples. I assert its a good Response Code, so the assertion will fail Response codes like 4xx and 5xx errors.
I'm curious, I store a user_id in a jmeter variable when a new user is created in my load script (which is available in jmeter for the entire thread/samplers/session)... Is there anyway i can output that variable via the Beanshell for **All** sampler requests **ONLY IF** there is an Error.

I already output user_id earlier for ALL requests right after creating a user via something like so:

```
log.info("user_id:"+ vars.get("user_id") ); //gotten via JSON Path PostProcessor earlier when creating User.
```

But I'd like do output something like so for all Response Assertion errors:

```
log.info("Response Assertion failure for user_id:"+ vars.get("user_id") );
```

maybe a 'BeanShell Post Processor' but dont really have a good idea how to hook that into the 1 Response Assertion whick checks the whole Thread Group so it only outputs to the log the user_id dynamically if there is Assertion failure.

Is there a worst case scenario, where I cant do it for all requests at the 'top level' of the Thread Group... but maybe I'd have to add Response Assertions on each request instead and only then I can dynamically add the output somehow?
(But if there is a way of doing it once for all requests would be cool/better)
Any ideas are welcome, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need a Response Assertion to check for 4xx and 5xx HTTP response codes, JMeter is smart enough to automatically mark HTTP responses with codes above 400 as failed.
2. You can add a [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) to print something into the log on sampler failure using code like:

   ```
   if (!sampleResult.isSuccessful()) {
       log.info("Response Assertion failure for user_id:"+ vars.get("user_id") );
   }
   ```

Where `sampleResult` is a shorthand for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance holding parent previous sampler result. See JavaDoc for all available methods and fields.

Depending on where you place the Beanshell Listener its scope will be different.

- If you put it on the same level as your samplers - it will be executed after **each** sampler, i.e. Sampler1 and Sampler 2

  [image: Sampler1 and Sampler2]
- If you put it as a child of the Sampler1 - it will be applied to Sampler1 only

  [image: Sampler1]

Check out [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using Beanshell test elements in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks for the photos, this is a great answer!